# Using PHP to handle CAS logins (migrating from JSP)

Tags: php, jsp, single-sign-on, cas

**Background:**

We currently have a fully functional CAS implementation using JSP, but want to migrate it to a PHP implementation.

Currently, we have a central CAS server that authenticates the user and redirects them to a landing page(in JSP), which then takes their authentication data and passes it onto a third-party-application.

In this JSP we use the following snippet to retrieve the user's data

```
String usr = request.getParameter("id");
String nid = session.getAttribute("netid");
```

**Question**

How do I retrieve this information using PHP?

I have tried doing:

- $_GET
- $_POST
- $_REQUEST
- $_SESSION

and more.

I have a feeling that I may need to install phpCAS in order to do this, but do not want to do so unless absolutely necessary.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every consumer of a CAS service ticket needs to be able to validate a token, parse the response, etc.  It seems like you're currently using some JSP-based CAS client which is doing the work for you? (possibly Yale's, as the Jasig one does not deal with JSP).  If you want to switch your client to a non-JSP/Java application, but to a PHP one, your best option is to protect that page/client application with phpCAS.  phpCAS will intercept the ticket in the url, validate it against the CAS server and set the appropriate session variables.

Here's a simple example of phpCAS in action:
https://github.com/Jasig/phpCAS/blob/master/docs/examples/example_simple.php

Alternatively, you can write your own interception/validation/parsing code, but since this is a security product, I recommend using one of the well-known/tested clients.